# A faster way to remove or apply filter on all worksheets once

Tags: excel, vba, filter

Need an easier or a faster way to remove or apply filter on all worksheets at once like something similar to ctrl + shift + L on all worksheets at once.

Don't know way to do - filter or apply filter all worksheets at once.

Comment: You could use VBA to loop trough each `worksheet`, if `filter` is on then remove else add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign a button or just run the macro when needs to loop through all worksheets and test for filter. The below code will get you started.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterToggle()

    Dim oWB As Workbook: Set oWB = ThisWorkbook
    Dim oWS As Worksheet
    
    For Each oWS In Worksheets
    
        With oWS
            If .AutoFilterMode = True Then
                .AutoFilterMode = False
            Else
                .UsedRange.AutoFilter
            End If
        End With
    Next oWS

End Sub
```